# Multiple Instagram/Facebook oembed not working

Tags: facebook, instagram, embed, oembed

I'm developing a WYSIWYG that let people embed posts from *Instagram* and *Facebook* using **oembed**.

The flow is that when the user enters an `url` the tool makes an API request to the **oembed** endpoint that returns an `html` field in its `json` response that is rendered into a page. 
The response looks like this: https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=http://instagram.com/p/V8UMy0LjpX/

When the user does this action, the `blockquote` returned gets transformed into an `iframe` via a request made by the `embed.js` `script` also returned by the request.

The second time the user tries to embed a post the `blockquote` doesn't transform itself into the `iframe`, which is bad because when it stays a `blockquote` it doesn't show the post.

This is happening for both **Facebook** and **Instagram**